# Warning from wordpress when try new post by xmlrpc

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc

When try post to wordpress by python-wordpress-xmlrpc get error

```
ExpatError at /syncFeed/1/
junk after document element: line 2, column 0
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/syncFeed/1/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: ExpatError
Exception Value:    
junk after document element: line 2, column 0
```

And if investigate error message I get response from wordpress

```
self    
<xmlrpclib.ExpatParser instance at 0x10ca61200>
data    
"<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  strpos() [<a href='function.strpos'>function.strpos</a>]: Empty                delimiter in <b>/home/itpod59/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php</b> 
on line    <b>4338</b><br />\n<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already         
sent by (output started at /home/itpod59/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-    server.php:4338) in 
<b>/home/itpod59/public_html/wp-includes/class-IXR.php</b> on line <b>475</b><br />\n<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/itpod59/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php:4338) in 
<b>/home/itpod59/public_html/wp-includes/class-IXR.php</b> on line <b>476</b><br />\n<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/itpod59/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php:4338) in 
<b>/home/itpod59/public_html/wp-includes/class-IXR.php</b> on line     <b>478</b><br />\n<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header "
```

i don't have idea how fix it. This code and example work fine in my mac, but get error on try it do with worpdress on production. And i try disable all plugins, doesn't help

Comment: Hi, I'm having this exact issue while posting to a client's Wordpress blog from our application. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: Just ignor this error in code